# Nonlinear ODE with coefficients depending on a derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $ t $ to be the independent variable and $ x(t) $ to be the unknown I want to solve the ODE for. Consider the following nonlinear nonhomogeneous ODE governing the dynamics of a real physical system:

$ f_1(k\dot{x}(t))\sin(x(t)) + f_2(k\dot{x}(t))\cos(x(t)) + f_3(k\dot{x}(t)) = g(t) $

where k is some scalar.

So it's a first order equation in $x(t)$, but as you see the functions $f_i$ are dependent on the first derivative.

(Or it could be a [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation)?)

Now my main questions are:

1- What are the conditions for existence and uniqueness?

2- How can I go about numerically solving this and what are the initial values I need? (is it just $x(0)$ or, $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$?)

Answer (score 1):

I presume $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ and $g$ are given smooth functions and $k \ne 0$. We want to consider
the equation
$$ F(p,x,t) = f_1(kp) \sin(x) + f_2(kp) \cos(x) + f_3(kp) - g(t) = 0$$
as implicitly defining $p$ as a differentiable function of $x$ and $t$.  The Implicit Function Theorem
says this is true at least locally if $\partial F/\partial p = k (f_1'(kp) \sin(x) + f_2'(kp) \cos(x) + f_3'(kp) \ne 0$.  So as long as that condition holds we should have the standard local existence and uniqueness theorem.

In Maple you could solve this numerically as a DAE (differential-algebraic initial value problem) for $x(t)$ and $p(t)$.

Since it's a first-order equation you should normally require the initial condition on $x(0)$, but if there is more than one solution of $F(p,x(0),0)=0$ you'll also need to specify which of those is $\dot{x}(0)$.

Comment: Yes all $f_i$ in the regime of interest are smooth and $k\neq 0$. So are you defining $p:=p(x,t)=\dot{x}(t)$?

Also I'm concerned by the fact that no derivative is a standalone. After what you did is this DE now in terms of  p or x?

One other note is usually the uniqueness and existence is written as $y' =f(t,y)$ with $y(t_0)=y_0$ provided. But here I can never make the derivative of that form?

Comment: In the DAE formulation, the DE is $dx/dt = p$ with the "algebraic" condition $F(p,x,t) = 0$.  In principle the differential equation is of the form $dy/dt = f(t,y)$, you just can't write an explicit "closed-form" formula for $f(t,y)$: it's just "the solution (in the appropriate interval) of $F(\cdot,y,t) = 0$".